# Easing transition doesn't seem to work on delay

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed height and width and upon clicking the label(checkbox trick) I expand the div to 100% width and height. That works, however the issue is in the transition.

I wish to create a easing transition where first the width expands and then the height expands. However upon defining the transitions the easing doesn't happen, instead it's like transition timing function goes to `step-end`. The transition happens instantly without easing(even though the delay on height transformation works).

tl;dr: The transition loses smoothness

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64aFD/4/)

Comment: 200ms isn't very much time in which to ease anything.

Comment: @Paulie_D increasing time doesn't change anything. Transition still doesn't flow but just instantly changes states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties can not be transitioned from different "metrics".

In the base state, you specify height in px; in the changed state, you specify it in percentage. That won't work.

You can set it to work somehow with some tricks, that are not fully satisfactory; the best of them is to use max-height to do the change

```
#cbox {
    display:none;
}

.someDiv {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;

    transition-property: width, max-height;
    transition-duration: 2000ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0, 2000ms;
}

#cbox:checked + div {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

I have also writen the transition in a way that can save you some typing when using multiple properties; notice that I can write ease only **once**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/64aFD/7/)

Comment: That worked, thanks for the help. I'll think about using js but for now this'll do perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate properties with comma, instead of writing them in same line, try this

CSS

```
    -webkit-transition: width 200ms ease 0s, height 200ms ease 200ms;
    -moz-transition: width 200ms ease 0s, height 200ms ease 200ms;
    -ms-transition: width 200ms ease 0s, height 200ms ease 200ms;
    -o-transition: width 200ms ease 0s, height 200ms ease 200ms; 
     transition: width 200ms ease 0s, height 200ms ease 200ms;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It flows for width, but height still jumps up. Is it an issue with percentages?

Comment: I run it on localhost and it works perfectly, however in jsfiddle it acts weird... btw, did you consider to us javascript or jQuery to do that transition?

Comment: I'm open for js, for jquery not that much. I don't really want to burden the website with 80KB if I don't use it that much. Though I'm not sure how could I make it work in js.